# different image for mobile template block theme

Tags: multisite, themes, mobile

I have a WP from a multisite.

I have no permissions to install anything so, for theme base I'll use Twenty Twenty-Two. I make a header and footer with an image as logo that display's in any format.

What I need is have a different image for header and footer but with Guttenberg there is no way to get a different template depending on device the home is displaying.
In the header code i have this:

```
<!-- wp:group {"style":{"color":{"background":"#ff00bc"}}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group has-background" style="background-color:#ff00bc"><!-- wp:columns {"style":{"color":{"background":"#ff00bc"}}} -->
<div class="wp-block-columns has-background" style="background-color:#ff00bc"><!-- wp:column {"width":"33.33%"} -->
<div class="wp-block-column" style="flex-basis:33.33%"><!-- wp:image {"id":219,"sizeSlug":"full","linkDestination":"none"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-full"><img src="mysite/blocktheme/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/FULLIMAGE.png" alt="" class="wp-image-219"/></figure>
<!-- /wp:image --></div>
<!-- /wp:column -->
```

And need to display mobile.png instead the FULLIMAGE.png image if mobile device is displaying.
How can I do this without FTP permissions, just using user interface?